# Website showing up as not secure because stream provider doesn't support SSL

Tags: javascript, php, html, ssl, internet-radio

So my dad has 10+ different websites for streaming radio. He uses a streaming URL provided by the radio to stream the music on his website. The problem is that most of these streaming URL's are http and not https. Because of this, certain pages for radio stations show up as non secure.

I know this is logical because all items you load into your page have to be over https in order for your page to be secure.

Is there any way/ any hack/ some workaround to make this work anyway. It's really annoying and I'm afraid it will affect his websites SEO.

The stream owners are not yet ready to change to https, and it will probably take another year for them to do this.

Comment: Not unless you want to run a proxy, which would likely be more expensive than it's worth.

Comment: put a reverse proxy in front (nginx, caddy etc) which you can add ssl to like lets encrypt etc, you also might get away with using cloudflare if you dont want the hassle or cost of spinning up a server

Comment: What protocol are these streams using?  HTTP Progressive (SHOUTcast, Icecast, etc.)?  Does he control the streaming servers?  (Could he switch providers?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My dad doesn't control the streaming servers, he only gets to use the streaming URL. Most of the streams use HTTP and don't support HTTPS.

How would I go about using cloudflare to fix this issue?

Comment: @Branko That depends entirely on what protocol is in use.  Which is it?

Answer (score -1):

Since you've tagged this question as PHP I assume that you can alter the website's code.
What you can do is create a simple script on your site which redirects to the radiostation.

https://www.yourwebsite.com/redirecttosomeradiostation.php

In 'redirecttosomeradiostation.php' you put:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.somenonsslradiostation.com');
```

Alternatively if you cannot use PHP scripts you could use an url shortener like Bitly in which you generate https forward urls.